# difference between module.exports.run and module.exports in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Title says it all. What is the difference between simple module.exports and module.exports.run in javascript? I really couldn't find some info on the internet. Sorry.

Comment: `module.exports` is an object that can be imported in other modules. `module.exports.run` would that be a property of that object. Not sure what else you want to know. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

`module.exports` is kindof like an index of what's exported in your file.

For example, if file.js starts with the line `module.exports = function(args) {`, when you import file.js using `const file = require("./file.js")` you can access your function using `file(arg1)`.

If file.js started with the line `module.exports.run = function(args) {` however, if the file was imported the same way, you could only access your function using `file.run()`.

Comment: I see but how can it be used? and why